# HTML CSS issue in a table layout with middle elements

Tags: html, css

I have a fiddle to illustrate my problem The code and css could be seen in fiddle.

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/tTv39/)

I am trying to create a simple HTML format as shown in the attached pic.

[image]

The problems is with "Loooong description" - As soon as I add a span or para below "Number" text to add "Loooong description", it changes the css of the parent too and "Number" doesn't remain on middle anymore!

Please note that all the sizes have to be in "%".

```
<div id="opentickets" class="container">
        <table class="outer wordwrap">
            <col class="cola" />
            <col class="colb" />
            <tr class="top">    
             <td colSpan="2" class="heading">Top Row Text</td>          
            </tr>
            <tr class="middle">
              <td ></td>
              <td class="wordwrap">
                <div  class="content"><b class="number">Number</b>
                </div>                  
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bottom"> 
             <td ></td>
              <td class="wordwrap"> </td>       
            </tr>
        </table>            
 </div>
```

ps: I had to create this table kind of format to achieve certain aspects (Number on middle of table and starting from 20% width etc), therefore I would appreciate if someone could guide me an extension to the css of this format only.

Comment: [Why tables for layout is stupid](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html)

Comment: And it's really not that clear what kind of behavior you're trying to get

Comment: I am just looking for a way to be able to add some text "long description" below the "Number" text - but the conditions are - a) "Number" should still be in center b) "long description" should be able to take all the space below Number including bottom row (but it should be left justified with the number itself"

Comment: @Tintin please start coding with nice clear div's from scratch.

Comment: With Divs I am unable to get the number as vertically on middle.  Can someone guide me on how to get it without using table. Please change the fiddle link - I have tried many ways with div but in vain.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @Itay Can you help getting this kind of layout without tables? I tried with divs but I was unable to get "Number" in the middle.  And also my current problem remains as it is, even with divs.  Thanks.

Comment: @Itay IE8,9,10, chrome and mozilla. Thanks.

Comment: Not to mention that I need all the sizes in % and no absolute or fixed layout'ing.  these will go inside iframews later and should support resizing of browser windows etc.  Thanks.

Comment: This is the best I could do in this hour. http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/tTv39/2/

Comment: There's a small jQuery plugin that can fix that. Are you instrested?

Comment: Thanks @Itay I could only use jQuery but not any extra plugins for that.

Comment: Thanks Italy but well its not the same!  1) the number is centered - I wanted to have it started on 20% from left and 2) the long description below it is not left justified with the "Number".